# Meaning of "that's the idea"

Tags: idioms

I read a book in which a character wrote a poem. 
She told herself

> I should fix the first part, but that's the idea.

What does this mean, "but that's the idea"?

Does it mean

1. she should fix the first one, but she is doing well over all.
2. she should fix the first one, and this idea (to fix the first part) is good.

Comment: Then the second part "but that's the idea" presents the meaning of "This is wrong, but you can infer the concept from what I've given you"

Comment: [Dictionary entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that%27s-the-idea?q=that%27s+the+idea)

Comment: Without a more complete context, I think this is essentially a matter of opinion. For example, the speaker might mean *"The general idea expressed by the poem [**or** the first part of the poem] is what I wanted to say"*. **Or** she might mean *"One of the basic principles of writing poetry is that you should repeatedly review and revise what you've written, so it's perfectly okay that I plan to fix the first part of this poem"*. **Or** something else.

Answer (score 1):

1. is my vote. Reworded one might say, "I should fix the first part, but you've got the right idea."

Comment: Reworded I'd say, "I should fix the first part, but what I've got written should give you the general idea."  I'd hesitate to assume and say, "You've got the right idea" until I had actually heard them regurgitate the idea to see if it matches.

Comment: Yes I actually meant to write that as "you've got **the** idea" but to your point I would completely agree and say "that's the idea"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really ambiguous because the word "but" tells you that the correct interpretation is 1, where the second clause is a contrast to the first.  If the word "but" was omitted, the preferred reading would shift to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I always took this to mean "that's the gist of it". That is, "the first part is not very good, but the idea is there all the same." or "I should fix the first part, but overall the poem says what I want it to"

Answer (score 0):

To me, this character seems to want to fix the first part of her poem, but refers to the poem's main idea or theme casually and/or a little vaguely. I think she is implying the first part of the poem is its main idea or main message.